# mod_rewrite - get domain and tld

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to allow referrers based on a whitelist using a `RewriteMap`. Because I want only the domain and tld in my `whitelist.map` I want to extract those parts from the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` and test on that.

To illustrate it:

The referrer could be:

```
http://www.example.com/somepage.html
```

and I want to test for

```
example.com
```

So far I got the following code and I guess the regex part is not working well:

```
RewriteMap whitelist txt:whitelist.map

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\/$
RewriteCond ${whitelist:%2.%3|NOT-FOUND} =NOT-FOUND
RewriteRule ^.* http://www.somewhere-else.com/ [R,L]
```

With the `whitelist.map`

```
## whitelist.map
## List of allowed referrers

example.com yes
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteMap whitelist txt:whitelist.map

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*?)([^.]+\.[^./]+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond ${whitelist:%1|NOTFOUND} NOTFOUND
RewriteRule ^ http://www.somewhere-else.com [R,L]
```

Note: this code assumes that whitelisted domains are first-level domains (not like `.co.uk` for example)